# How to find out the element with same set of values by SQL

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, I want to find out the elements whose value set are the same.

For example, I have a table of Enrolls, which contains Student, Course like:

```
Student Course
------- ------
Alice   OS
Alice   Network
Bob     OS
Bob     Network
Carl    Database
Carl    Network
-------------
Expected output: Alice, Bob
Because they are taking the same set of courses
```

What I want is to find out Alice and Bob, since they are taking the same set of courses. Do I have to use a cursor or something like that? Thank you.

Comment: Please post your requirement properly with at least sample data, it may be tough for us to help you with the present question.Edit your question well and I am sure you will get lots of help

Comment: Sorry for the poor typesetting just now.

Comment: Which database are you using? What is your expected result?

Comment: @Yiyang What if there is another set of courses?  If there are multiple people taking those courses, what do you expected as output? Also, which database are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I'm using SQLite, and if another student is taking only the OS and Network, I want to output them as well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using where clause and having clause together to find out all the student that are taking a particular set of courses (and group concat them as your output expects):

```
select group_concat(student)
from (
    select student
    from enrolls
    where course in ('OS', 'Network')
    group by student
    having count(distinct course) = 2
    ) t;
```

If you want to find student that are enrolled **only** in the two courses, do:

```
select group_concat(student)
from (
    select student
    from enrolls
    group by student
    having count(
        distinct 
        case when course in ('OS', 'Network') 
        then course end
        ) = 2
    and count(distinct course) = 2
    ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Yiyang - Glad to help out. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please consider accepting/upvoting that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Data Preparation Part :

```
Declare @StudentCourse table
 (
    StudentName varchar(30),
    Course varchar(30)
 )

 Insert into @StudentCourse
 select 'Alice','OS' union all
 select 'alice','Network' union all
 select 'Bob','OS' union all
 select 'Bob','NetWork' union all
 select 'Carl','Database' union all
 select 'Carl','Network'
```

You can use the XML Path function to concatenate the courses under one student. Store this result set in temp table. Please find the query below for this:

```
Select StudentName,
Stuff(
      (
        select ','+ Course from @StudentCourse where StudentName = 
        temp.StudentName for XML path('')
      ),
     1,1,'') as Courses into #tempTable
From (select distinct StudentName from @StudentCourse )temp
```

Use below query to see the result set:

```
select * from #tempTable
```

Now, you can use following query to see the students with same set of course:

```
select t1.StudentName, t1.Courses from #tempTable t1 join 
(
  select Courses from #tempTable group by courses having count(1)>1
) as tmpCourses 
on t1.Courses=tmpCourses.Courses
```

I hope this helps.